# IndexError: list index out of range when save model in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

Can anyone help me? i use tensorflow to train LSTM network. The training run well but when i want to save the model, i get error below.

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 0.0146, Training Accuracy= 1.000
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 0.0129, Training Accuracy= 1.000
Optimization Finished!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\lstm.py", line 169, in <module>
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "modelslstm/" + str(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")) + ".ckpt")
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1314, in __exit__
    self._default_graph_context_manager.__exit__(exec_type, exec_value, exec_tb)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3815, in get_controller
    if self.stack[-1] is not default:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My Code :

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    # from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
    # mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
    # a,b = mnist.train.next_batch(5)
    # print(b)
    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("trainlstm", sess.graph)
    #print(str(data.train.num_examples))
    for step in range(1, training_steps+1):
        for batch_i in range(data.train.num_examples // batch_size):
            batch_x, batch_y,name = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            #hasil,cost = encode(batch_x[0][0],"models/25-09-2017-15-25-54.ckpt")
            temp = []
            for batchi in range(batch_size):
                temp2 = []
                for ti in range(timesteps):
                    hasil,cost = encode(batch_x[batchi][ti],"models/25-09-2017-15-25-54.ckpt")
                    hasil = np.reshape(hasil,[num_input])
                    temp2.append(hasil.copy())
                temp.append(temp2.copy())
            batch_x = temp
            # Reshape data to get 28 seq of 28 elements
            #batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, timesteps, num_input))
            #dlib.hit_enter_to_continue()
            # Run optimization op (backprop)
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                                 Y: batch_y})
            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc))
            f.write("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc)+"\n")

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "modelslstm/" + str(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")) + ".ckpt")
f.close()
```

i added tf.reset_default_graph() but it doesn't work.
please help me to solve my problem.
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `self.stack` is empty, but it's trying to be indexed. It's that your code?

Comment: how can it happened? in my another code, i use same method but the model saved successfully. :(

Comment: Is the `self.stack` part of your code? Evidently you're letting it go empty when it shouldn't be allowed to. Why it's happening depends on the code, and if looks like it's not listed here. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: nope. the self.stack is the tensorflow core code. It isn't part of my code.

Comment: Then the data you're giving it might be invalid. Read over the docs of the functions you're using to make sure you aren't violating any preconditions.

Comment: solved my problem. I changed the `with` statement with make a new instance statement. It seems the destroying instance is having hard time. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use context manager (`with` statement on line 1?). It seems that the context manager is having a hard time destroying your object. This may be a problem in the `__exit__` builtin. Suggest that you submit a bug report to the developers.

Comment: It works!. Thankyou. i didn't expect that the `with` statement will make this. Thankyou

Comment: Please let the developers know by adding an issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues Also please tick the green tick next to the answer if it worked for you.